# Configuring Jenkins and Git/GitHub

Tags: git, github, jenkins

This is my first foray with Jenkins, and I've installed it on Windows 2008 R2.  I have also installed the "Jenkins GIT plugin" as well as the "GitHub plugin".  Below you'll see an image where I've combined by project setup (trying to connect to the GitHub repository) and below the blue break is the Git setup for Jenkins.  Can anyone tell me what the red error message means?  It looks like the command is incorrect - the fact that the executable is missing from the path seems weird, but that could be my ignorance.

Running "ssh git@github.com" in Git Bash comes back with a success, so my ssh keys seem to be installed correctly (and I'm not dealing with an authentication error here).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered a similar issue and suspect it might due to a bug in the Jenkins Git Plugin, having a problem with my corporate web proxy.

Setting git config for http.proxy and https.proxy works from the shell, but not for Jenkins Git Plugin.

As a temporary workaround I have had some success setting SCM to **None** and then adding a **Build Step** of **Execute Shell** as follows:

```
if [ -e ".git" ]
then
    git pull
else
    git clone --progress -o origin https://github.com/matthesrieke/nasa-wwj-maven.git .
fi
```

This script simply clones the git repo on the first build, or updates it on subsequent builds.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the answer provided by gb96 is that the job will not be triggered whenever a change is pushed.

My machine has a linux installation with http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables set. I also set http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort (and the https variants) system properties on glassfish and even tried to run jenkins standalone with those properties set. Nothing worked. I admit i had to resort to gb96's solution until i found out that jenkins has a page to set the proxy... its location is not very user-friendly, but just go to Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Manage Plugins and select the Advanced tab. Fill in proxy host, port, username (if any) and password (if any) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want Jenkins to pull your code from GitHub and build it locally, use the GitHub read-only URL format (git://github.com/user/repo.git) in the Repository URL field.  Then you won't run into any authentication issues.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same exact error, just updated to reflect the "git://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git" url.  Also, this doesn't seem to be an authentication error so I would have been surprised if this would have worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure these GIT properties in Jenkins.

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```